# 独自ドメインの設定をAPI経由で行いたい

Tags: heroku

最近 Heroku を使い始めたのですが、APIに関する情報が探せずに困っております。

独自ドメインを Heroku で利用できるということでさっそく試していたのですが、コントロールパネルから登録するのが煩わしいので、Linux(CentOS,Ubuntu)から curl コマンドか何かで叩いて変更（DNSの削除 and 登録）をすることは可能でしょうか？

↓毎回この画面で削除したり、登録したり・・・↓
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

APIでDNS情報を登録、削除したりしたいので、リファレンスページをご存知の方いらっしゃいましたら紹介して頂けないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

その手の情報はDev Centerに集約されています。

該当機能はこれのことでしょうか？
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#domain

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます！  
Dev Center に記載されていたのですね。  
さっそくここを参考に色々と試してみようと思います。